# Moving x2 axis when dragging x axis

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.graph-objects

I am plotting two series of data with Plotly / Graph Objects / Dash, which are referenced to x and x2 axis respectively. When I drag the x axis, I need curves referenced to the x2 axis to move in the same way. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
      x=x,
      y=df['Receita Bruta'],
      offsetgroup=0,
      xaxis='x2',
))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
      x=x,
      y=df['Investimento'],
      offsetgroup=0,

))

...

fig.update_layout({
      'xaxis2': {
              'overlaying': 'x', 
              'side': 'top',
      },
  })
```

Is there a way to move the x axis (by dragging the numbers) and make the same movement to the x2 axis? The following picture is what I am getting.

[image]

I have found a reference (https://community.plotly.com/t/updating-x2-axis-when-sliding-x-axis/24581) but the answer says to block the drag losing the feature.

One thing I tried was adding `achor: 'y'` in both xaxis and xaxis2, but I am understanding this is not the objective of this parameter.

Thanks in advance.